# Find all $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which satisfy $ f(m-n+f(n))=f(m)+f(n) $

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, functional-equations

**Question** -

Find all $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which satisfy the relation -

$$
f(m-n+f(n))=f(m)+f(n)
$$
for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ where  $N={1,2,3....}$

**solution** -

Observe $f(n) \geq n .$ Consider $F(n)=f(n)-n .$ Show that $F$ satisfies
$$
F(F(n)+m)=F(m)+n
$$
Using this, **conclude that $F(1)=1$**

and $F(n+1)=F(n)+$
$F(1)$ for all $n \geq 1 .$ Thus $F(n)=n F(1) .$ It follows that $F(n)=n$ and $f(n)=2 n$

***Now i did not understand how they proved $F(1)=1$ ???***

Any help will be appreciated

thankyou

Comment: Is this function well defined? How do you know that $$m-n+f(n)>0$$ is true for all $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how he proved it, but here's my solution:
$$f(m-n+f(n))=f(m)+f(n) \implies P(m,n)$$
$$P(0,0) \implies f(f(0))=2f(0)$$
Let $f(0)=c$  giving $f(c)=2c$, so
$$P(m,c)\implies f(m+c)=f(m)+2c $$
$$P(m,0) \implies f(m+c)=f(m)+c $$
So, $c=2c \implies c=0 \implies f(0)=0$
$$P(n,n) \implies f(f(n))=2f(n)$$
Let $f(1)=k$
$$P(1,1) \implies f(k)=2k$$
$$P(m,1) \implies f(m-1+k)=f(m)+k$$
$$P(m-1,k) \implies f(m-1-k+2k)=f(m-1+k)=f(m-1)+2k$$
So, combining the previous 2 equations, we get
$$f(m)+k=f(m-1)+2k \Leftrightarrow f(m)-f(m-1)=k \implies H(m) $$
$$H(2)\implies f(2)-f(1)=k \implies f(2)=2k$$
$$H(3)\implies f(3)-f(2)=k \implies f(3)=k+f(2)=k+2k=3k$$
and so on, by simple induction, and the fact that $f(0)=0$
$$f(x)=kx \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \in \mathbb{N}$$
Substituting in the original equation,
$$km-kn+{k^2}n=km+kn \Leftrightarrow {k^2}n=2kn \Leftrightarrow k^2=2k \Leftrightarrow k^2-2k=0 $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow k(k-2)=0$$
This gives $$(1) \text{  } k=0 \implies f(x)=0 \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \in \mathbb{N}$$ 
$$(2) \text{   } k=2 \implies f(x)=2x \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \in \mathbb{N}$$
the only 2 solutions $\Box$.

Note that when $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{N}$, you can discard all the steps of relating to $0$ and the proof would still hold true.

Comment: i have clearly mention in question that N=1,2,3.....!!!

Comment: @User88463 
I edited that: note that you can discard all the steps relating to zero and the proof would still hold true for $f(x)=2x$ only

Answer (score 0):

$f(0)+f(0)=f(f(0))$

$f(0)+f(f(0))=f\bigg(0-f(0)+f(f(0))\bigg)=f\bigg(0-f(0)+f(0)+f(0)\bigg)=f(f(0))$

Subtracting $f(f(0))$ each side we get $f(0)=0$

$f(0)+f(n)=f(n)=f(0-n+f(n))\iff f(n)=f(f(n)-n)$

$f(m)+f(n)=f(m)+f(f(n)-n)=f\bigg(m-f(n)+n+f(f(n)-n)\bigg)=f\bigg(m-f(n)+n+f(n)\bigg)=f(m+n)$

Thus $f$ is linear with $f(0)=0$ so $f(n)=an$.

Reporting in equation $f(n)+f(n)=f(f(n))\iff 2an=a^2n\iff a=2, a=0$

Thus $f(n)=2n$ or $f(n)=0$

Comment: but N does not contain 0 !!!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so I will do it here
for @zwim: you are using the functional equation for m negative (in $f(0)+f(n)=f(n)=f(0-n+f(n))\iff f(n)=f(f(n)-n)$)

My solution:
Let us consider $h(n) = f(n) - 2n$. $h$ verify the functional equation:
$$h(m+n+h(n)) = h(m) - h(n), \text{ where } h: \mathbb{N}_{>0} \to \mathbb{Z}$$
we extend $h$ to $\mathbb{N}$ by $h(0) = 0$.
In particular we have: $h(2n + h(n)) = 0$.
So if there exists $n_0 > 0$ s.t. $h(n_0) = 0$, we have $h(m + n_0) = h(m)$ so $h$ is $n_0$-periodic.
Let $0 < i < n_0$, we put $h_i = h(i)$. We have
$$h(n+i+h_i) = h(n) - h_i$$
and by induction:
$$h(n+k(i+h_i)) = h(n) - kh_i$$.
By choosing $k = n_0$, we conclude $h_i = 0$, so by periodicity we have $h(n) = 0$, so $f(n) = 2n$.
Otherwise, if there isn't $n_0>0$ s.t. $h(n_0) = 0$, then from $h(2n+h(n)) = 0$
we conclude $f(n) = 0$.

Comment: $h$ is from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$. If you exclude $0$ from $\mathbb{N}$ (which is $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$) then the only solution is $f(n) = 2n$

Comment: ok, but can you pls tell me how F(1)=1 in my original doubt that actually i have....i just wanted to know that how they write $F(1)=1$ after substituting $F(n)=f(n)-n$ ? if this doubt will be cleared then i have very easy solution for this problem...

Answer (score -1):

let $F(n) = f(n) - n$. $F$ verify the functional equation:
$$F(m + F(n)) = F(m) + n$$
By choosing $m=0$, we have $F(F(n)) = F(0) + n$, so $F$ is injective.
By letting $n=0$, we have $F(m+F(0)) = F(m)$ and by injectivity we deduce
$F(0) = 0$.
Now we have $F(F(n)) = n$ so now $F$ is surjective. Let $n_0$ s.t. $F(n_0) = 1$.
We have now:
$$F(m + 1) = F(m) + n_0$$
so:
$$F(m) = n_0 m$$
by inserting this into last equation we deduce $n_0^2 = 1$ so $n_0 = 1$.
I have prouved $F(1) = 1$. Now by induction we deduce $F(n) = n$, i.e. $f(n) = 2n$

Comment: are you serious ??? i have told many time in this post that N=1,2,3....